# How to load admob ads into a unity 5 project?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, admob

Basically I'm trying to load a banner ad into my Unity 5 project and export to iOS.

Here is the code i'm calling inside of unity which is attached to a game object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdController : MonoBehaviour {

    InterstitialAd interstitial;
    BannerView bannerView;

    void Start () {

        //------ Banner Ad -------
        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        // Put your Admob banner ad id here
        bannerView = new BannerView(
            "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
        // Create ad request
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);        
        bannerView.Show();

        //---- Interstitial Ad -----
        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        // Put your admob interstitial ad id here:
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        //Add callback for when ad is loaded
        interstitial.AdLoaded += HandleAdLoaded;

        // Create an ad request.
        AdRequest requestInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        interstitial.LoadAd(requestInterstitial);
    }



    public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args) {

        interstitial.Show ();
    }


    void OnDestroy(){
        if (interstitial!=null) {
            interstitial.AdLoaded -= HandleAdLoaded;
            interstitial.Destroy ();
        }
        if(bannerView!=null){
            bannerView.Destroy ();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using:

- Unity 5.0.1f1
- Xcode 6.3
- Google Unity Plugin 2.2.1
- Google Ads SDK 7.2.1

Has anyone got this to serve ads? Note: I did replace the xxxxx with the correct Ad Unit ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an  project  on GitHub:

[Unity Admob Plugin](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob)

it easy to use,and I have success with this.

```
using admob;
...
Admob.Instance().initAdmob("admob banner id", "admob interstitial id");//admob id with format ca-app-pub-2796046890663330/756767388
Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative(AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add some code to your unity project

   - add this c# class to your Unity project
   - call the functions of this class somewhere from your project
2. Call the constructor "AD_AdsiOS" as early as possible and pass your AdMob ad ID
3. Call "ShowInterstitialAd" to show a fullscreen ad
4. Call "ShowBannerAdTopRight" to show a banner ad at top right
5. Call "HideBannerAds" to hide the banner ad​

```css
#if UNITY_IPHONE
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
public class AD_AdsiOS
{
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _initAds(string p_adMobID);
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _showInterstitialAd();
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _showBannerAdTopRight();
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _hideBannerAds();
#endif
 
    public AD_AdsiOS(string p_adMobID)
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("AD_AdsiOS: will not work in editor.");
#else
        _initAds(p_adMobID);
#endif
    }
 
    public void ShowInterstitialAd()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("AD_AdsiOS: ShowInterstitialAd called in editor.");
#else
        _showInterstitialAd();
#endif
    }
 
    public void ShowBannerAdTopRight()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("AD_AdsiOS: ShowBannerAdTopRight called in editor.");
#else
        _showBannerAdTopRight();
#endif
    }
 
    public void HideBannerAds()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("AD_AdsiOS: HideBannerAds called in editor.");
#else
        _hideBannerAds();
#endif
    }
}
#endif
```

- compile to Xcode
- STEP 1 DONE :)

  2. Manage Libraries in Xcode (source: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/)
- Download the AdMob SDK
- Create a new folder in your project root folder called "GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS"
- Copy all files from the downloaded SDK (but not the "Add-ons" folder) into the new "GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS"
- Right click your project ("Unity-iPhone") and press "Add-Files to Unity iPhone" and select the new "GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS" folder in your project's root
- Open the Link Binary With Libraries dropdown under the Build Phases tab. Add the frameworks from the iOS SDK using the + button that becomes visible. Add SystemConfiguration, StoreKit, MessageUI, AVFoundation and AdSupport to both targets (check troubleshooting step 1 and 2)
- You now need to add -ObjC to the Other Linker Flags of !THE PROJECT! (not the targets)
- STEP 2 DONE :D

  3. Add some code (source: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)
- add the following two files to the "Classes" folder of your project and import them

MyAdMobAdsImpl.h

```
#ifndef __Unity_iPhone__MyAdMobAdsImpl__
#define __Unity_iPhone__MyAdMobAdsImpl__


void InitMyAdMob(UIView* p_rootView, UIViewController* p_rootController);
void DestroyMyAdMob();

#endif /* defined(__Unity_iPhone__MyAdMobAdsImpl__) */
```

MyAdMobAdsImpl.mm

```css
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADInterstitial.h"
 
#include "MyAdMobAdsImpl.h"
 
NSString* _adMobID;
UIViewController* _adRootViewController;
GADBannerView* _adBanner;
GADInterstitial *_adInterstitial;
float _adBannerRelWidth;
float _adBannerRelHeight;
 
extern "C"
{
    void _initAds (const char* p_adMobID)
    {
        _adMobID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:p_adMobID];
 
        _adBanner.adUnitID = _adMobID;
 
        _adInterstitial.adUnitID = _adMobID;
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [_adInterstitial loadRequest:request];
 
    }
 
    void _showInterstitialAd ()
    {
        [_adInterstitial presentFromRootViewController:_adRootViewController];
        // get next add
        _adInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
        _adInterstitial.adUnitID = _adMobID;
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [_adInterstitial loadRequest:request];
    }
 
    void _showBannerAdTopRight ()
    {
        _adBanner.hidden = NO;
        // force refresh
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [_adBanner loadRequest:request];
    }
 
    void _hideBannerAds ()
    {
        _adBanner.hidden = YES;
     }
 
    float _getAdsRelativeWidth () { return _adBannerRelWidth; }
 
    float _getAdsRelativeHeight () { return _adBannerRelHeight; }
}
 
void InitMyAdMob(UIView* p_rootView, UIViewController* p_rootController)
{
    _adRootViewController = p_rootController;
    // Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    // Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
    _adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin] autorelease];
    [_adBanner setRootViewController:p_rootController];
    [p_rootView addSubview:_adBanner];
    // ios frame size is not rotated -> exchange width-height
    _adBannerRelWidth = kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width / p_rootView.frame.size.height;
    _adBannerRelHeight = kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height / p_rootView.frame.size.width;
    _adBanner.center = CGPointMake(_adBanner.center.x+
                                   MAX(p_rootView.frame.size.height-kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width,
                                       p_rootView.frame.size.width-kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width),
                                   _adBanner.center.y);
 
    // Initialize the interstitial ad
    _adInterstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
}
 
void DestroyMyAdMob()
{
    _adBanner.delegate = nil;
    [_adBanner release];
 
    [_adInterstitial release];
}
```

These two files implement the AdMob logic. With this code it is possible show and hide banner ads in the top right corner and to show fullscreen ads. Additionally, with getAdsRelative* you can get the size of the banner in relative screen space (0.1 for width would mean that the banner takes 0.1*Screen.width pixels). Those methods are not references in step one for simplicity, but you can use them if you need to.

- Now the "InitMyAdMob" and "DestroyMyAdMob" methods must be called from Unity classes
- Open the "UI/UnityAppController+ViewHandling.mm" file
- Add following code below the last #include:
  Code (CSharp):

```css
//// ******************* ////
//// *** AdMob START *** ////
//// ******************* ////
  #import "MyAdMobAdsImpl.h"
//// ******************* ////
//// *** AdMob END   *** ////
//// ******************* ////
```

- Add following code to the "createViewHierarchy" function just before "[_window makeKeyAndVisible];"
  Code (CSharp):

```css
 //// ******************* ////
    //// *** AdMob START *** ////
    //// ******************* ////
    InitMyAdMob(_rootView, _rootController);
    //// ******************* ////
    //// *** AdMob END   *** ////
    //// ******************* ////
```

- Add following code to the beginning of the "releaseViewHierarchy" function
  Code (CSharp):

```css
//// ******************* ////
    //// *** AdMob START *** ////
    //// ******************* ////
    DestroyMyAdMob();
    //// ******************* ////
    //// *** AdMob END   *** ////
    //// ******************* ////
```

- STEP 3 DONE :p

  4. Troubleshooting
- 1. if you get "library not found for -liPhone-lib" make sure to move it to the top in Build Phases tab->Link Binary With Libraries dropdown
- 2. if you get "Undefined symbol ... _OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo" add CoreTelephony in Build Phases tab->Link Binary With Libraries dropdown
- 3. if you get about 20 errors all within the NSObjCRuntime.h or some similar NSObjC* file:
     make sure that the 'File Type' dropdown is set to 'Objective-C++ Source' (in the far right column when you select a file) for the files you add to the project. This way it treats the files correctly and uses the right paths and stuff.
     source: http://forum.thegamecreators.com/?m=forum_view&t=201075&b=41
- 4. in the newer XCode version with the newer AdMob Version additional Libraries need to be added (EventKit.framework and EventKitUI.framework). Or you will get:
     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEvent", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventEditViewController", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)

http: //stackoverflow.com/questions/25950990/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-when-add-admob

Comment: http://a2dr.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-integrate-admob-into-unity-5-ios_31.html  for more help ..

Comment: The example you gave above is targeting an older version of the AdMob SDK and an older version of Xcode.