# AdMob SmartBanners on Unity covers rest of the GUI

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

On Unity AdMob smart banners overwrite the screen, potentially hiding UI elements that are below them.

Is there a way to:

- Automatically resize the main UI canvas accordingly, or
- know the shown banner ad height, or
- activate the banner ad as a texture inside a predefined UI object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30212078/290072

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it